# How do I create a 3D polygon from a series of 3D points in three.js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js

I wonder what would be the best way to generate a custom 3D polygon given an array of 3D points in three.js. It is a simple polygon without holes. The points are ordered so that they represent neighboring vertices.[I can do it in 2D, but I don't want the vertices to be coplanar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJwmW.png)
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is how to create a 3D mesh from a bunch of points. In other words: you need to figure out which of the vertices should be connect to form a triangle.

This is an surprisingly complicated thing to do (well, at least I was surprised) and there are tons of scientific papers, libraries and so on about that.

However, in your case it is a bit simpler as you already know roughly how the vertices should get connected. I would recommend you have a look at the [earcut-library](https://github.com/mapbox/earcut) or [libtess.js](https://github.com/brendankenny/libtess.js), both of which should be able to create the triangulations you need.

Once you have that, you can roughly go with [@lior-trau's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41708295/123219) recommendation for how to create the geometry from the result.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old but someone who's looking for an answer as I did may try to use [ConvexGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/geometries/ConvexGeometry) or [ConvexHull](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=conv#examples/en/math/convexhull/ConvexHull)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35671334)