# How do i make custom Shapes from an array of points in xyz with THREE.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

As an Example: i have the points [1,0,2],[2,0,2],[3,2,5]
Now i would like to make a shape from these points by connecting them.

I tried to use THREE.Shape but it can only build the shape on the x and y axis.
I need to use the z axis to build the shape aswell.
I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41706208/10221765

Comment: Are all of these points co-planar?

Comment: @prisoner849 yes i want to create a 2d shape so all points are on the same plane but in 3d space :)

Comment: :) Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274103/4045502), and related forum topics: [topic1](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/2d-object-in-3d-space-by-vertices/2795?u=prisoner849), [topic2](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texture-on-dynamically-created-object/2994?u=prisoner849)

Comment: @prisoner849 this worked quite well thank you! One question is it possible to extrude it with extrudegeometry? If so could you show me what code you would add? https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry

Comment: Well... you can do this trick with quaternions. Rotate a set of points to XY plane, create shape, extrude it, and apply a reverse quaternion to the points of the extrude geometry.This is how I see it, but I may be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

An instance of [THREE.Shape](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/extras/core/Shape) is a 2D shape. In other words, it always lies in a conceptual plane. It's not possible to define an arbitrary 3D structure with it.

`three.js R104`

Comment: Is there any other way to make the shape i need ?

Comment: Using [ConvexBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/geometries/ConvexBufferGeometry) could be an option. Check out the linked example in the doc page for a complete live demo.